# Can we create subdomain dynamically on Amazon EC2 server

Tags: codeigniter, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I have created one CI project where user can register and get his/her own domain. eg my project is on example.com then user can create user1.example.com, user2.expample.com, etc sub domain.

I have created virtual host and database for them separately but not able to create sub domain dynamically on amazon server EC2.

suggest me any api to create sub domain dynamically once my user register with us